# Push result into array after each loop iteration

Tags: arrays, loops, pine-script, pine-script-v5, pine-script-v4

How can we get the result for i=2 to be pushed onto index 0 of the array and i=3 to be pushed onto index 1? at the moment I am getting the SUM of i=2 + i=3 in index 0 and 1 as it shows on the image below:

```
myArray = array.new_float(0)

var counter = 0

for i = 2 to 3
    if close > ta.sma(close, i)
        counter += 1
    array.push(myArray, counter)

if barstate.islast
    label.new(bar_index, 2, str.tostring(array.join(myArray, " - ")))
    label.new(bar_index, 1, "array size: " + str.tostring(array.size(myArray)))
```

[image]

//////////////////////////////////

and it should be:

[image]

and

[image]

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not completely sure how to easily change your code to get what you want, but you can use the `matrix` to achieve this (as some kind of a dictionary workaround).
Basically what you can do is lose the `counter` variable, and update the values directly to the `matrix`.

```
//@version=5
indicator("My script", overlay = true)

var myMatrix = matrix.new<float>(2, 2, 0)

for i = 2 to 3
    matrix.set(myMatrix, 0, i - 2, i)
    if close > ta.sma(close, i)
        matrix.set(myMatrix, 1, i - 2, matrix.get(myMatrix, 1, i - 2) + 1)
  
if barstate.islast
    label.new(bar_index, 3, str.tostring(myMatrix))
```

**EDIT:**

If you really wish to do the same with `array`, you can use the same logic, but since pine scrip currently isn't supporting dictionaries, you'll need to use 2 separate arrays:

```
//@version=5
indicator("My script", overlay = true)

int start = 2
int end = 3

var my_array = array.new_float(end - start + 1, 0)
loop_index_array = array.new_int(end - start + 1, 0)

for i = start to end
    array.set(loop_index_array, i - start, i)
    if close > ta.sma(close, i)
        array.set(my_array, i - start, array.get(my_array, i - start) + 1)   

if barstate.islast
    label.new(bar_index, 3, str.tostring(my_array))
    label.new(bar_index, 4, str.tostring(loop_index_array))
```

Comment: Thank you mr_statler, this worked like a charm. I am not very familiar with matrixes, would it be any way to do it with arrays?

Comment: You can think of Matrix as a table in which each row is an array. that way, you can "stack" multiple arrays onto one "table". In any case, I've edited my answer to do the same with an array.